# Location of Fiat Panda electric power steering fuse

Tags: electrical, power-steering, fiat

A friend of mine has a 2006 Fiat Panda. As these cars are wont to do, the electric power steering has malfunctioned. So, what we want to do is completely disable the power steering so that the long drive to the workshop isn't a dangerous ordeal with an intermittently malfunctioning power steering motor.

Does anyone know where the power steering fuse on a 2006 Panda is, or how else to disable it? The owner's manual is no help. There are two fuse location diagrams but neither mention the EPS system (Electronic Power Steering).

Comment: It is *probably* a relay in the underhood fuse box (as a guess). It may be called something else there besides EPS.

Comment: There's nothing there remotely related to power steering unfortunately. The Fiat Punto's fuse box has it labeled as something like Power Steering. But then again, I think that car has hydraulic power steering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to use an auxiliary fuse block near the battery for high current fuses. The power steering seems like a good candidate for this.

I did a Goggle search for ["fiat panda power steering fuse location"](https://www.google.com/search?q=fiat+panda+power+steering&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC9IP-oIHRAhVS92MKHaUFBD4Q_AUICSgC&biw=1373&bih=914&dpr=2#tbm=isch&q=fiat+panda+power+steering+fuse+location) and found the manual page below that shows the location of the fuse in a fuse block under the hood on the driver's side outboard of the battery. The fuses appear to be in a black plastic housing forward of the upper strut mount. The fuse itself appears to be the 40 Amp one that they are labeling as 'G' in the illustration.

Another option would be to disconnect the cable connector going to the power steering unit.

[image: Page from manual showing fuse location]